# Have international aid agencies given Gaza $US8,300 per capita?

Tags: hamas, gaza

According to [this December 2023 transcript](https://matzav.com/kennedy-backs-israel-heated-debate-erupts-as-rfk-stands-up/), (I don't have access to the original interview), Robert Kennedy told Krystal Ball:

> The international aid agencies have given Hamas, have given Gaza more than 10 times per capita what we gave to rebuild all of Europe after the Marshall Plan. They’ve gotten $8,300 per capita, every person in Gaza.”

Is it true that international aid to Gaza over the years has equalled $8,300 per capita?

Comment: Something to note the value of the money given in 1945 will be worth a lot more in 2023. https://www.usinflationcalculator.com/

Comment: @Oddthinking, isn't per-capita income of other states, and therefore relative wealth of Gaza, empirical?

Comment: @YouDontSay: You are conflating several economic concepts. Income is not the same as wealth. International aid is not the same as personal income. There are relationships between them, but whether $8,300 per capita aid would make Gaza wealthy is a question for Economics.SE.

Comment: Does he give any sort of timeline for when this aid was given? Because $8300 for the ~2.3 million people in Gaza is about $19 billion, which could sound very high or very low depending on how many years of aid he's talking about.

Comment: @Oddthinking, fair points. However why can't that be part of an answer to the question as originally stated? Notable claim by Kennedy:  $8300 aid per capita = Gaza would have been one of the wealthiest states on the Mediterranean. Is that true? That was the second part of the OP question.

Comment: The problem with the claim is that the $621 per capita in 1945 translates into around $10,500 in 2023 which suggests that Gaza is actually getting less than we gave to rebuild Europe.

Comment: From the [US Archives](https://www.archives.gov/milestone-documents/marshall-plan): "[O]n April 3, 1948, President Truman signed the act that became known as the Marshall Plan. Over the next four years, Congress appropriated $13.3 billion for European recovery." That would have to be divided by about 21,417,000 people to get $621 per capita, if anyone is wondering about the other half of the claim.

Comment: @YouDontSay: Go ask on Economics, where people can come up with their own, economic models, and happily argue over their opinions, rather than here where empirical data is required.

Comment: "*more than 10 times per capita what we gave to rebuild all of Europe after the Marshall Plan*" The Marshall Plan was about rebuilding Europe, it's strange to reference aid **after** the Marshall Plan.

Comment: @JoeW, or he could have meant $621 per capita in today's dollars, translating to $36.64 in 1945 dollars. If someone can track down some data it would be great.

Comment: [According to the Organization for Economic Cooperation and Development, aid to Palestinians totaled over $40 billion between 1994 and 2020.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_aid_to_Palestinians#:~:text=The%20international%20community%20has%20sent,%24600%20million%20in%202020%20alone.) But it's not clear if this is Gaza only.

Comment: @Giter: Indeed, Israel cumulatively received some $158 billion in US aid according to a CRS report from March. https://sgp.fas.org/crs/mideast/RL33222.pdf That's far more than the Marshall plan, per capita.

Comment: The Marshall plan was  "over $13 billion (more than $150 billion in today's dollars" according to another source. But clearly Western Europe had far more population than Israel (or Gaza).

Comment: @Gitter And Africa supposedly received $1 trillion in aid cumulatively https://www.scielo.org.za/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S2222-34362015000400001 Divided by today's population that's about the same as the Marshal plan, funnily enough. But there were fewer people in Europe when the Marshal plan was disbursed. It's also not clear how the population should be counted over such long periods.

Comment: I would find that to be very unlikely as your quote doesn't mention inflation at all.